# Are there built-in "parallel" functions for boolean operations?

Tags: r, function, boolean, logical-operators

I'm looking for a function similar to `pmax` and `pmin` but for boolean operations.

For example:

```r
parallel_and(
  c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
  c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
  c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
  c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)
```

With an expected output of:

```r
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

`magrittr::and` is an alias for `` `&` `` so only two vectors are accepted (and I'd like to avoid including an extra dependency in my code).

Comment: Is `mapply(all, ...)` what you're looking for?

Comment: You can try `parallel_and <- function(...) pmin(...) > 0`

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```r
bools <- list(
  c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
  c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
  c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
  c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)

Reduce(`&`, bools)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pmin` to design your `parallel_and` function like below

```
parallel_and <- function(...) pmin(...) > 0
```

such that

```
parallel_and(
    c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
    c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
    c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
    c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)
```

gives

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: This would be even cooler if you generalized it like `parallelize <- function(myfunc, ,mycrit, ...)  myfunc(...) > mycrit`   (not tested)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That sounds an interesting proposal! Sometimes we need to identify what `myfunc` we really need for our the target. For example, we use `pmin` (not `&`) to do things like `parallel_and`.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to data.frame and use rowSums:

```
d <- data.frame(bools)
rowSums(d) == ncol(d)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Another 'left-field' idea:  convert bools to a simple array, then

```
matrixStats::rowProds(bools)
```

or

```
matrixStats::colProds(bools)
```

That will take care of the AND operation you are doing.
EDIT: a quick test shows Stephane's method to run much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean by 'parallel'?

```r
library(parallel)

parallel_and <- function(...){
  mcmapply(function(...) all(...), ...)
}

parallel_and(c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
             c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
             c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
             c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I suspect the OP meant "rowwise", and not parallel as in parallelized computing. Maybe `mapply` is enough, no need for `mcmapply`.

Comment: I think you're right @GuedesBF - thanks. Regardless, I'd say Stéphane's or TIC's answers are better than my approach :)

Answer (score 0):

We can `t`ranspose the list, then loop-apply a logical function like `all` or `any`, and finally `unlist` if necessary.

```
bools <- list(
    c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
    c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
    c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
    c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)

bools |> t() |> lapply(all) |> unlist()

[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If the arguments to the function must be multiple vectors instead of a list, we can list them inside the function, then do the same:

```
parallel_and <- function(...) {
    list(...) |> t() |> lapply(all) |> unlist()
}
```

Comment: Works but kinda the long way around :-)

Comment: yeah, not the best answer, which is definitely @Stephane Laurent's