# How does the function 'Reduce' handle list variables?

Tags: r, list, reduce

I found a creative use of `Reduce` by StephaneLaurent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76482089/).
That is, in a comment about handling a list variable, he wrote

```
Reduce(`&`, bools)
```

where `bools` is a list variable.
When I looked at the help page for `Reduce` , it says the input argument `x` should be a vector.
But the referenced code feeds  a list variable.

Apparently the list variable is treated as though the first element in each list are combined into a vector, then the second in each list, etc. Can someone explain what is going on in the "guts" of `Reduce` to allow this apparently undocumented capability?

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question so it can be self contained and you can point out exactly what you are referring to. I don't see StephaneLaurent  or Reduce at all on the question you linked to. There is a bit of imprecisions in what R calls a vector sometimes. For example `is.vector(list(1,2,3))` returns TRUE. So reduce is probably just using the more relaxed definition of vector where it really just means a collection it can iterate.

Comment: Section 2.1 of `R-lang` gives the most precise description.  If a help page deviates from the definition then arguably there is a bug in the documentation. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-lang.html#Basic-types

Comment: @MikaelJagan, well, the documentation does say explicitly "Lists are vectors, and the basic vector types are referred to as atomic vectors where it is necessary to exclude lists." But I don't think that's how most R users commonly use the terms. But I don't think the help page is wrong, it's consistent with the language guide.

Comment: @MrFlick  my apologies for cut/paste the wrong link.  I fixed it so it now points to the correct page.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [R Language definition](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-lang.html#List-objects)

> Lists are vectors, and the basic vector types are referred to as *atomic vectors* where it is necessary to exclude lists.

So a list is a vector so the behavior isn't undocumented. Reduce will walk the list applying a function to each item in the list along with the output of the previous iteration. So these are the same

```
bools <- list(
  c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
  c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
  c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
  c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)

Reduce(`&`, bools)

((bools[[1]] & bools[[2]]) & bools[[3]]) & bools[[4]]
```

Comment: Thanks!  My confusion stems from the fact (?) that you can't simply index into a list via  `foo[j,k]` operations.   So `Reduce` does something unexpected in that sense.

Comment: Doing `foo[i]` with an atomic vector is the pretty much the same as `foo[[i]]` with a list. That's the best way to index each element in the collection and R takes care of doing the correct indexing for you. It's not unique to `Reduce`. For example the same happens with `sapply`: `sapply(c(1,2,3), function(x) x+1)` and `sapply(list(1,2,3), function(x) x+1)` both return the same thing.

Comment: Yes, that part I understand.  But while `foo[[5]][3:8]`  works as expected,  one cannot execute `foo[[3:4]]`  .  Anyway, I think we're in complete agreement as to how  `R` works :-)